# Ruby on Rails bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying use bootstrap modal with ajax, the problem is that when i click the screen gets darker but the modal never shows.
Any help or is there a better way of doing this?
[image: Rails console]

measures/index.html.erb

```
 <%= link_to 'Show', measure,remote: true, class: 'static-popup-link'%>
 <div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">Loading...</div>
```

application.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var clickOnPopupLink = function(){
      $('body').on('click', '.static-popup-link', function(){
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
   });
  }

  clickOnPopupLink();

});
```

measures_controllers.rb

```
def show
end
```

show.js.erb

```
$('#myModal').html("<%= j render('/measures/modal')%>");
```

measures/modal.html.erb

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;          </button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
       .........
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `$("#myModal").show();` instead of `$('#myModal').modal('show');`

Comment: Is `jQuery` less, than 3? They changed a behaviour of `show` in last release.

Comment: It doesn't work, anyways thanks.

Comment: Ok try this `$(".static-popup-link").click(function()` instead of `$('body').on('click', '.static-popup-link', function()`

Comment: doesn't work either, and i tried it with $("#myModal").show(); and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing hide class from below mentioned div will serve your purpose

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">Loading...</div>
```

Comment: make modal.html.erb a partial and use render('partial_name')

Comment: Did this work? Is the advice to remove "hide" where it appears here: <div class="modal hide fade" and then to save the modal as a partial instead of as a top level file?